# No more space available under /root

Tags: 20.04

My system is telling that I have no more space available.

```
mktemp: failed to create directory via template ‘/tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: No space left on device
```

Although command `df -i` shows:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5  3080192  388666  2691526   13% /
```

The command df -h shows:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5   46G   44G  502M  99% /
```

I previously added 12GB to my system from a bootable USB. How can I correct this?
Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that max amount of inodes my disk space can possibly have, was not updated upon disk space expansion. If that is the case. Is there a way I can update it?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1285181/edit) to show the complete output of both `df -h` and `df -hi`.

Comment: Thank you. The command `df -h` I can see that I was using close to 99% of my disk space. `.git` was using more than 10GB. I removed it.